# How to find distance to / detect mouseover on scaled shapes in Processing

Tags: java, processing

In Processing (2) I am currently creating a Java class diagram in a UML-ish sort of style. Classes, Interfaces and the like are represented as rectangles, created using processing's `rect()` method. A class is created for each rectangle to be displayed storing information about it, with a `display()` method which draws the rect.

In order to implement zooming in and out of this diagram (to facilitate very large or very small projects), I have added code which changes a `scale` variable each time the mousewheel is scrolled in and out. The code then uses Processing's `scale()` method each time the class rectangles, etc, are drawn.

I am also attempting to detect when one of these rectangles is moused over. This is currently done with the following code inside the class representing a rectangle:

```
//Checks to see if a mouse X and Y (posX and posY) position is inside the rectangle.        
public boolean positionCollides(int posX, int posY) {
        boolean xCollides = false, yCollides = false;

        if((centreX + (width/2) >= posX) && (centreX - (width/2) <= posX)){
            xCollides = true;
        }

        if((centreY + (height/2) >= posY) && (centreY - (height/2) <= posY)){
        yCollides = true;
        }

        if(xCollides && yCollides){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Where `mouseX` and `mouseY` are fed into that method. Note in this code `centreX` and `centreY` are variables which contain(ed) the co-ordinates of the centre of the rectangle when it was first created.

However, when I zoom in and the scaling is applied to the rectangle's `display()` method, the mousing over breaks - presumably because the things are displayed at slightly different X and Y co-ordinates and it's still checking the old ones.

Is there a way I can change my above `positionCollides` method to help it deal with the result of the scaling? How can I get this sorted?

I've attempted to sort this by putting the code which calls `positionCollides` after the `scale()` call in the display method (in an attempt to get the mouseX and mouseY values to scale as well), and by multiplying mouseX and mouseY by the scale (ie 0.9, 1.1) to try and get them to the correct values.

Perhaps there's a way I can alter the object's centreX and centreY dynamically?

Thanks for reading my wall of text.

**tl;dr** - How can I detect if the mouse pointer is inside a shape/rectangle which has been scaled in Processing?

Comment: I've had a quick look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112584/how-to-calculate-the-dist-from-mousex-mousey-to-a-rectangle-in-processing?rq=1 - but using dist() or the answer posted seems to be suffering from the same problem?

Comment: Perhaps you need to apply the scale yourself?

Comment: What exactly would the scaling in this case be applied to? I'll have a shot at applying scaling to some of the variables inside positionCollides() . The reference - http://processing.org/reference/scale_.html - is a tad confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this:

(tested in processing 1.5)

```
int x, y, sz;
float factor = 0.87;//any value here
float transx = 50;//any value here
float transy = 25;//any value here
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  x=100;
  y=100;
  sz=50;
}


void draw()
{

  noFill();
  //draw at original positon, no fill
  rect(x, y, sz, sz);
  scale(factor);
  translate(transx, transy);
  fill(255);
  //draw after scalling and positioning filled this is tested for insidness
  rect(x, y, sz, sz);
  if ( mouseX / factor - transx > x    && 
       mouseX / factor - transx < x+sz && 
       mouseY / factor - transy > y    && 
       mouseY / factor - transy < y+sz)
  {
    println("i'm inside!!!");
  }
  else
  {
    println("i'm outside");
  }
```

}

Comment: Tried it in Processing 2, that seems to work! I'll just have a go at putting this into my Java Processing code...

Comment: should not be hard, just add "/scale - translateProperAxis" to your test.

Comment: How did you arrive at the figures for transx and transy?

Comment: Just global variables so i can test against. I gave them an arbitrary value to test. They are not needed if you don't translate, just scales. But I included for completeness. Glad it worked :)